# Processing all subviews from cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have a `UITableView` with some cells in it. These cells consist of several subviews (an image, a label and an accessoryView). When a user presses this `accessoryView` I need to get some data from the cell in order to process the touch. I'm having no success though. What am I doing wrong?

This is the button I add as the `accessoryView`:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
button.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(showNormalActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.tag = indexPath;
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

And this is the method it calls:

```
- (IBAction)showNormalActionSheet:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *categories = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"categories"];

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath);
    NSString *name;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    for (UIView *i in cell){
        if([i isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
            UILabel *newLbl = (UILabel *)i;
            name = newLbl.text;
        }
    }

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Add %@", name]
                                                             delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    for( NSString *category in categories)  {
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:category];
    }

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

It keeps throwing errors, mainly `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x799c7740'`.

Comment: `for (UIView *i in [cell subviews])`?

Comment: Possibly `for (UIView *i in [cell.contentView subviews])`?

Comment: The biggest mistake you are making is that you are trying to access data from the cell. Don't do that. Get the data from the same data model used to populate the cell.

Comment: You have it - `indexPath`. Use the row and or section as needed to access your data model.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from the answers above, I was able to rewrite the method in a much better way:

```
- (IBAction)showNormalActionSheet:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *categories = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"categories"];

    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];

    NSString *name = [[self.searches[indexPath.row] name] capitalizedString];

   UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Add %@", name]
                                                             delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];

    for( NSString *category in categories)  {
        [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:category];
    }

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

This doesn't pass any data. It just fetches it from the same datamodel.